# Multiple keybindings on one key?

Tags: java, swing, key, key-bindings, keystroke

I am making a piano with JFrame but I have a little problem.
I want the key of the piano to turn green when it's pressed, and a note to play.

```
b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('q'), "playD");
b.getActionMap().put("playD", playC);      //playC refers to another Action class       

b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('q'), "SetBg");
b.getActionMap().put("SetBg", db);  //db refers to another Action class
```

However, these methods override eachother.
Right now, only the colour changes, and the note isn't played.
If I remove the "SetBg" method, the note does play.

Is there any way to fix this?

A second problem I have is that I can't seem to get it to work to know when a key is actually released again.
I tried `.put(Keystroke.getKeyStroke("released q"), "DoSomething");`
But that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *How Key Bindings Work* section of [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) explains that. "If more than one binding exists for the key, only the first valid one found is used."

Comment: It also says "Because the order of searching the components is unpredictable, **avoid duplicate WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW bindings!**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this, but I don't think that you can add two key bindings on the same key stroke without the 2nd binding blocking the first and all previous bindings. In other words, I believe that only a single binding is possible for each specific keystroke and input map.

Having said that, I'd do this differently:

- I'd structure my program to conform to one of the Model-View-Control (MVC) design pattern standards.
- I'd have my binding be part of the Control,
- The Action's only function will be to change the Model's state, here being that the *something* key has been pressed or released.
- The Model can have many View listeners, and they can all respond as they see fit to the change in the model's state, and here is where I'd have my two different responses to the Model's change be located.

Comment: Thank you! I did it a bit differently and it works now.